# YouTube API - "Unknown error occurred on the server"

Tags: youtube-api

We've just started receiving weird errors from the YouTube API, as follows:

{u'error': {u'code': 500, u'message': u'Unknown error occurred on the server.', u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'Unknown error occurred on the server.', u'reason': u'internalError'}]}}

We're calling the https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports endpoint. Does anyone know what this could be? As it's returning a 500 error code it would suggest that there  is an actual bug / crash at the YouTube end?

Any direction / assistance on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

500 errors are backend errors. That could be a transient error. We'll act on it and if it persists.